# typeof (undefined variable) causing error...?

Tags: javascript

```
alert(typeof QuizParser.Parser.otherdata['response_set']['answers']["slide_" + _index]['trt']);​
```

Why? Shouldn't this simply alert the string `undefined`? If this is wrong, how should I check to see if that variable is defined or not?

Comment: You're not typeof-ing one variable, but properties of an undefined object.

Comment: You are probably interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with `typeof`, it's because you're attempting to access a property of an undefined variable: `QuizParser.Parser`

Comment: Thank you! I thought an undefined field of an undefined object would still logically be undefined.

Comment: @yahfree: That's the problem...there's no such thing as an "undefined object".  `undefined` is not an object, and doesn't convert to one, so trying to treat it like one (in your case, taking a property of it) will get you a ReferenceError.

Comment: For clarity, an attempt is made to read the property called "Parser" of the undefined variable `QuizParser` (the value of `QuizParser.Parser.otherdata` is never read, because an error is thrown before that).

Comment: @Rob: Long as we're clarifying, the error gets thrown before even attempting to read `QuizParser.Parser`, when you try to look up `QuizParser`.  (Unlike object properties, variables pretty much have to exist -- a variable that doesn't exist throws a ReferenceError when you attempt to use it pretty much anywhere outside a `typeof`.)

Comment: @cHao Have to disagree - he's got a typeof in front of it.  The undefined variable is allowed there.  It's the dot notation attempting to access the property of `QuizParser` that's causing the error.

Comment: @Madbreaks: Disagree all you want.  And then fire up a V8 console and type these lines in order:  `typeof x.y`, `x = undefined;`, `typeof x.y`.  See if the error doesn't change from "ReferenceError: x is not defined" to "TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined".  Proving that the first problem is that the variable doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @cHao It's much easier than that, try this at the console `typeof QuizParser`. LMK.

Comment: @Madbreaks: `typeof QuizParser` works.  `typeof QuizParser.**anything**` doesn't, because QuizParser doesn't exist.  If you say `QuizParser = undefined`, you get an entirely different error.

Comment: That is *exactly* what I said in my original answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Madbreaks: No, you didn't.  You said "the dot notation attempting to access the property of `QuizParser`" is what's doing it.  And the first error is not caused by trying to look up a property.  It's caused by the fact that you're attempting to use `QuizParser` (which doesn't exist) outside the context of `typeof QuizParser`.  If you set it to `undefined` and then tried again, you.  would.  get.  a.  whole.  other.  error.  Because you would have gotten past the first one (the nonexistent variable).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `typeof`, it will return `"undefined"` for undefined variables, but in your case you are actually doing other things before calling `typeof`. `QuizParser.Parser.otherdata` must be defined in order for `typeof` to not cause an error. For example, if `x` is not defined, `typeof(x)` is okay but `typeof(x.something)` will cause an error since you are trying to access `x` which is not defined (in order to access something)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not that easy, if you choose the direct way: you'd have to write something like...

```
if (typeof QuizParser !== 'undefined' // to check whether the variable defined or not
    && QuizParser.Whatever            // if variable IS defined, we can check its property directly
    && QuizParser.Whatever.Property... 
)
```

Take note that we cannot skip the 'middle' chains: if property doesn't exist, it will be evaluated to undefined, and the next step will throw a TypeError: `Cannot read property ... of undefined`.

But there's another way (and it's quite common in many cross-browser libraries) - use exceptions to catch 'missing links' instead:

```
try {
  var flag = QuizParser.Whatever.Property.You.Like['equal']['to']['something'] !== undefined;
} catch(e) {}
if (flag) { ... }​ // processing goes here
```

With this you can more-o-less emulate `isset` behaviour from PHP: your `flag` variable will be set to `true` if and only if that endpoint property of the target object is set (= not `undefined`). And with exceptions mechanism you guarantee that no error will be thrown at your client (stopping the JS parsing altogether) otherwise...

Answer (score -2):

It's not the `typeof` that's the issue. It's the fact that inside the `typeof`, before the "typeof" part is actually executed, you're trying to access members of a null object. For example, consider this scenario (and note that it isn't javascript, but it's the idea I'm trying to get across, not the language syntax)

```
public class Test
{
    public string teststring;
}
```

and then you do something like this:

```
Test nullTest; // null

if(typeof(test.teststring) != null)
```

the second the parser sees the dot after test, a nullreference error is thrown, since you're essentially trying to call null.teststring. 
Instead, you have to do something like:

```
if(object != null && object.property != null && object.property.propertyOfTheProperty != null) 
//...
```

so that the execution of the if statement would be broken before anything dangerous could ever happen. If knowing about `object`'s or `property`'s nullness is important to you, you can also do this:

```
if(object != null)
{
    if(object.property != null)
    {
        if(object.property.propertyOfTheProperty != null)
        {
           //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @cHao nor is what I wrote, necessarily. But the ideas still apply, and it would have taken a lot longer to show the same concept in javascript

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, whoever. I wish I could downvote your thought process that caused you to believe that javascript has anything whatsoever to do with this question.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt *Not my dv* But concepts from Java are not by definition applicable to JavaScript. Throwing in Java is only confusing.

Comment: @RobW lol, evidently I have to break it down a little. The concept that the OP is coming across is that you can't access members of a null object. That concept applies to java (or C# which is technically what I was going for), in the **exact same way** that it does to javascript. I reasonably assumed based on the context of the question that the OP would understand it just as well in a syntax that, in my opinion, makes the issue at hand much easier to understand.

Comment: You might wanna break it down a little more.  See, an undefined object in JS is not `null` -- in fact, if your value is `null`, it's defined!  Starting to see why the language is important yet?  (BTW, not my downvote either, but i considered it.)

Comment: @cHao Again, that is (almost) totally irrelevant. It's the *idea* that is important.

Comment: And the *idea* would be a lot less muddied if you'd presented it in terms of the language in the question.  And no, `null` not being `undefined` is pretty freaking relevant, cause you make a point of comparing stuff to it and all that.  `null` and `undefined` are different values, and if you compare.....eh.  Screw it.  -1 til you can bother explaining in terms of JS.

Comment: @cHao Jesus. the *idea* of null is still the same. I get what you're saying. You don't have to explain javascript 101 to me. I'm employed full time as a web developer. Null != undefined. Right. The point you're too dense to understand is that I could just as easily have written `if(property != "the amount I enjoy arguing with people on stackoverflow")`, and it would have had the exact same effect. Sure, in javascript, that isn't null, but the point is still clear. I can safely assume that the OP, being a sensical human being, wouldn't think that you can just take C# code and throw it into some

Comment: @chao javascript code, and everything works all nice and well. You, on the other hand, don't seem as up-to-par with that idea. But that's fine, keep your -1, and I'll keep my answer, thanks.

Comment: @cHao on nicer terms, I'd like to add the (fairly important) qualifier that `the amount I like to be proven wrong` (is even nuller than) `the amount I enjoy arguing with people on stackoverflow`

Comment: Oh, i get the idea.  But we're talking about people who might not know this stuff.  You can't safely assume that the guy asking a JS question knows how different C# is, or understands the difference between `null` and `undefined` and simply "doesn't exist".  He's here *because* he's not a JS pro.